# Detecting a URL is open in the browser or not - Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, browser

In my application, there is a custom requirement to detect whether a URL is open in the browser, (i.e. it could be in another tab, another window etc.). Is there a way to detect the same?

It can be in a rails way or using client side scripts.

I'm not sure its a good question or not.

Answer (score 1):

The only contribution I could make would be about how it could work:

---

**Requests**

Because [Rails works on requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), I would suggest the only way to "know" whether a certain URL is "open" is to use a perpetual connection ([WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or [long-polling](http://www.xphp.info/php-tutorial/long-polling/))

By using a websocket, or [long-polling](http://www.xphp.info/php-tutorial/long-polling/), you'd have a constant reminder of who's requesting your controller actions, thus providing you with information on which are open

---

**Connection**

If you're using websocket or long-polling technology, you could do it like this:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def your_action
    #can accept xhr requests 
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js { render nothing #xhr request}
    end
end

#app/assets/application.js
if (!!window.EventSource) {
    var source = new EventSource(window.location);
}

source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
   console.log(e.data);
}, false);
```

[Good tutorial here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)

This will continually request the page you're on with [`SSE`'s](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) (essentially using long-polling), thus allowing you to see if the action is open

This is super sketchy, but hopefully it will give you some ideas

Comment: Thanks dude :). I'll check and reply you